How to make mv work with exotic directory names?
I created several scripts to move messages tagged via notmuch notmuch between Maildir directories.
Having multiple accounts, I have some issues with the names of some directories mbsync created when syncing with gmail.
Here is my typical Maildir structure for gmail accounts:
gmail-user2
├── [Gmail]
│   ├── Brouillons
│   │   ├── cur
│   │   ├── new
│   │   └── tmp
│   ├── Corbeille
│   │   ├── cur
│   │   ├── new
│   │   └── tmp
│   ├── Messages envoy&AOk-s
│   │   ├── cur
│   │   ├── new
│   │   └── tmp
│   ├── Spam
│   │   ├── cur
│   │   ├── new
│   │   └── tmp
│   └── Tous les messages
│       ├── cur
│       ├── new
│       └── tmp
└── Inbox
    ├── cur
    ├── new
    └── tmp

When I run the following script:
function safeMove { s=${1##*/}; s=${s%%,*}; mv -f $1 $2/$s; }
echo Moving $(notmuch count --output=files tag:trash and tag:gmail-user2 and not path:/.*/Corbeille/ and not path:/.*/Trash/) trash-tagged mails to gmail-user2 Trash folder
for i in $(notmuch search --output=files tag:trash and tag:gmail-user2 and not path:/.*/Corbeille/ and not path:/.*/Trash/); do
    safeMove $i ~/Maildir/gmail-user2/[Gmail]/Corbeille/cur
done

I have the following error:
mv: cannot stat '/home/user1/Maildir/gmail-user2/[Gmail]/Tous': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'les': No such file or directory

How could I make mv find the Tous les messages directory?
EDIT:
According to the links provided in the comments I added double quotes:
function safeMove { s=${1##*/}; s=${s%%,*}; mv -f $1 $2/$s; }
for i in "$(notmuch search --output=files tag:trash and tag:gmail-user2 and not path:/.*/Corbeille/ and not path:/.*/Trash/)"; do
    safeMove "$i" ~/Maildir/gmail-user2/[Gmail]/Corbeille/cur
done

Now I have the following error:
mv: target '/home/user1/Maildir/gmail-user2/[Gmail]/Corbeille/cur/1715687008.294831_40.user1-um450': No such file or directory

When find ~/Maildir/ -name 1715687008.294831_40.user1* gives:
/home/user1/Maildir/gmail-user2/[Gmail]/Tous les messages/cur/1715687008.294831_40.user1-um450,U=40:2,FS


This and this.

And: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

Thank you @KamilMaciorowski and ilkkachu. I added the double quotes, but I now have another error (see edit)...

I'm not familiar with notmuch, but the documentation mentions a text0 format option that would allow you to do readarray -t -d '' files < <(notmuch search --output=files --format=text0 ...) to assemble the list of files unambiguously into an array...

... You can then access the count as echo "Moving ${#files[@]} trash-tagged mails to gmail-user2 Trash folder" and loop over as for i in "${files[@]}"; do stuff with "$i"; done avoiding having to search twice.

Thank you @steeldriver , readarray -t -d '' files < <(notmuch... improved the script, but unfortunately it still produces the same error...

Have you fixed the quotes inside the safemove function mv -f "$1" "$2/$s" or just in the loop "$i"?

When I add doubles quotes to safemode I have the same error: mv: cannot move '/home/user1/Maildir/gmail-user1/[Gmail]/Messages envoy&AOk-s/cur/1715688103.314112_520.user1-um450,U=504:2,S' to '~/Maildir/gmail-user1/[Gmail]/Corbeille/cur/1715688103.314112_520.user1-um450': No such file or directory

@steeldriver, your solution (readarray) worked after all. Could you post it as a solution, so I can accept it?

@crocefisso glad it worked, unfortunately the question is closed to new answers

@steeldriver, not any more. (you have a gold badge on [tag:bash] too, so you can also close as dup or reopen Qs tagged with it)

Is this caused by regular express path ? [Gmail] ?

@James I think I don't fully understand the causes of the problem, but from my understanding there were two issues. The first was caused by the lack of doubles quotes, and the second was solved by Steeldriver's snippet.  As he provided the solution for the latter, he might understand this issue.

@ilkkachu The role of this function is indeed to remove the end of the file names. I had to add it to prevent having file names with the same uid (U=n), which generated mbsync errors. I found the function here: https://notmuchmail.org/pipermail/notmuch/2019/028956.html

And it shouldn't cause an error if it's just the target filename. You'd get that error if one of the intermediate directories is missing, but the tree you show above seems to show they're all there.

I can't be sure here since I don't know what the output of this "notmuch" command is. However, as a general rule, you should avoid using for loops for things like this. See bash pitfall number 1. Instead, try with a while:
safeMove() { s=${1##*/}; s=${s%%,*}; mv -f -- "$1" "$2/$s"; }
notmuch search --output=files \
  tag:trash and tag:gmail-user2 and \
   not 'path:/.*/Corbeille/' and not 'path:/.*/Trash/' |
  while IFS= read -r i; do
    safeMove "$i" ~/'Maildir/gmail-user2/[Gmail]/Corbeille/cur'
  done

Note that this will still fail if your file names can contain newline characters. However, it looks like notmuch has an option for null-separated output, which means this should work:
 notmuch search --format=text0 --output=files \
  tag:trash and tag:gmail-user2 and \
   not 'path:/.*/Corbeille/' and not 'path:/.*/Trash/' |
  while IFS= read -rd '' i; do
    safeMove "$i" ~/'Maildir/gmail-user2/[Gmail]/Corbeille/cur'
  done


For Moving 209 trash-tagged mails to user2 Trash folder. I have 209 messages:
mv: cannot stat '/home/user1/Maildir/user2/Inbox/cur/1715688956.313930_5730.user1-um450,U=5730:2,S': No such file or directory etc. However, it seems to work. Thank you!

And does that file exist? What is the output of ls '/home/user1/Maildir/user2/Inbox/cur/1715688956.313930_5730.user1-um450,U=5730:2,S'? We can't see your file names, so it is really hard for us to debug this. Can you provide us with an example directory and file names? Something simple that we can use to reproduce?

I just replaced two different aliases by user1 and user2 all the rest are full copy-pastes. I notice that the script behavior is erratic, sometimes I have mv: cannot stat messages, sometimes I have no messages, and sometimes I have messages saying mv: '.../Maildir/user1/[Gmail]/Spam/cur/1715688925.313930_5446.user1-um450' and '/home/user1/Maildir/gmail-user1/[Gmail]/Spam/cur/1715688925.313930_5446.user1-um450' are the same file. I think the problem comes from Google and what mbsync receives from it.

I found the issue, it didn't come from Google, but from another part of my script (the code discussed here is just a small part of it). Your code works perfectly and there was actually two things to change in the code I posted in my question: the double quotes and the null-separated output. Thanks again!
